# Android location - no matter how I implement it, I never get the location marker icon in the notification bar

Tags: android, google-api, gps, location, locationlistener

I am trying to implement location in an Android application. 
I first tried the approach that I have learned from paid courses - extending the LocationListener. I tried working with the "best provider" returned by locationManager.getBestProvider, but I found out that it is too often GPS, which returns 0,0. 
So I changed everything to using 3 providers: gps, network and passive. Am displaying all latLng and accuracy from all 3. It is often the same, though the GPS returns 30% of the time 0,0.

Than I changed the whole approach to using GoogleApiClient. Implemented GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener and LocationListener.

The values here are somewhat similar to what I get with the first approach.

But no matter what I do, I never get the location marker icon in the notification bar. Like for google maps or any call-a-taxi app. 
Why is this?

Also, in both cases the apps appear in the "Recent location requests" in settings; the application name for LocationListener, and the Google App/Google Location History for the second approach.

I am testing on Nexus 4 (with stock 5.1.1) and 5 (stock 6.0.1) devices. Permissions are in the manifest, and added the necessary permission check for API level 23.

the Mainactivity classes can be found here: 
[using Google API](http://cristianbell.com/tmp/MainActivity_gapi.java)
and [using LocationListener](http://cristianbell.com/tmp/MainActivity_locListener.java)
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Why not post the code here instead of keeping them on an external site?

Comment: because it is waay too long and would make the post very annoying to read. And since the implementation is almost from the google examples, wasn't sure that it brings much to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location marker notification icon appear only if you use the `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` on the method

> lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, this);

if you use `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` there no will be a icon in the status bar

**EDIT :**

Check aswell your location mode in `Settings->Location->Mode` set it to high